# Asp.net web api mvc 500 internal server error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a 500 internal server error when I make an api get call on my Incomecontroller.
Its really odd since I can make post calls successfully. I'm sure nothing is wrong with my repository or service coz I tested dem real well.

```
[Authorize]
public class IncomeController : ApiController
{
    private IIncomeService _incomeService;
    public IncomeController(IIncomeService service)
    {
        _incomeService = service;
    }

    public List<Income> Get()
    {
        return _incomeService.GetAllIncome();
    }

    public Income Get(int incomeId)
    {
        return _incomeService.GetIncome(incomeId);
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]Income values)
    {
        Income income = new Income(
            values.Description,
            values.Amount,
            values.StaffId
            );

        _incomeService.CreateIncome(income);
    }
}
```

My service below is injected using unity
`IIncomeService`

```
public interface IIncomeService
{
    void CreateIncome(Income income);
    Income GetIncome(int id);
    List<Income> GetAllIncome();
    Dictionary<string, int> GetMonthlyIncome();
    Dictionary<string, int> GetYearlyIncome();
    void Update(Income income);
}
```

If it's relevant I have two roles for the application. `Manager` and `Employee`. And I used token based authorization.

Below is d ajax call to d api using jquery

```
function getAllSavedIncome() {
    var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/Income",
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var refined = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the exception message is that causes the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Yeah I would add one if there was. Unfortunately I don't get any exception thrown from the code running on visual studio. Nothing breaks